# Help explain what “miseries were as vast as the sky” mean

Tags: meaning, comparatives, literary-english, simile

I'm totally confused about the use of this phrase in this situation:

> After Margaret Sanger saw the worst of many women who had to do abortion with abortionists, they suffered from physical pains and even death. She wanted to find a way to help them, She said: 
>   *'I resolved to do something to change the destiny of these mothers, whose **miseries were as vast as the sky**.'*

Comment: "as vast as the sky" simply means "very big".  Enorme, gross, kyo .. like that

Comment: Bigger than a breadbox.

Comment: Help us understand what's confusing to you about this.

Answer (score 2):

'I resolved to do something to change the destiny of these mothers, whose **suffering** was **immense**.  (or **enormous**)